# Hide the uploaded filename string after file uploaded that appears next to the upload button

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I have a form that allows a user to upload a jpg/mp4 file, by default it will show the uploaded filename next to the 'Upload' button.

I am trying to prevent the browser from showing the uploaded filename next to the 'Browse/Upload' button (I know this is very silly but it is a request that I am required to change).

```
<input id="file-upload" type="file" ngf-select="onFileSelect($files)" accept="image/*">
```

so if I upload a file named 'soccer.mp4' - I do not want the word 'soccer.mp4' to appear next to the upload button - is there any simple to hide/remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible since there is no DOM node for it. You cant change it via CSS or JavaScript but you are able to replace it with an button created by a simple directive - like I created in this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljwzxbwp/).

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myUpload" accept="/image" styled-upload-button />
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}).directive('styledUploadButton', function ($compile ) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var el = $compile( '<button onclick="document.getElementById(\''+ attrs.id +'\').click()">Upload</button>' )( scope );
      element.parent().append(el);
      element.css('display', 'none');
    }
  };
});
```